# Are there any performance issues in having two different file systems on the same disk?

Tags: partitioning, ext4, btrfs

I am planning to re-install Ubuntu and mount my / as a btrfs partition, while keeping /home on ext4. Are there any performance issues in doing so. I read this guide some time back to migrate my /home to another partition:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

But the guide recommends against having two different filesystems on the same disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different filesystems have different performance characteristics. For instance, ReiserFS (which is no longer an install-time option for Ubuntu) has a reputation for working well with small files, whereas XFS works well with big files. Journaled filesystems (like all modern Linux filesystems, including both ext4fs and Btrfs) recover rapidly after a power outage, whereas non-journaled filesystems (like ext2fs and FAT) take a long time to repair after a power outage. Btrfs has advanced features that are similar to those provided by RAID or LVM configurations, such as striping and snapshotting.

I haven't studied recent filesystem benchmark data, and in particular, I don't know how ext4fs and Btrfs compare -- what types of usage scenarios would be best for each filesystem. Btrfs is certainly a more advanced filesystem, and if you need features like snapshots, it might be a good choice on partition(s) that need those features. That's something you'd need to evaluate based on your specific needs, though; you've provided no information that would be helpful in providing advice on this score.

As others have noted in their comments, using two filesystems *per se* will not significantly impact performance -- the extra driver and cache considerations are trivial on modern hardware. I'd be more concerned about whether switching from ext4fs to Btrfs is appropriate *for your `/home` specifically.* The answer may depend on what types of files you store, how you access those files, what Btrfs-specific features you intend to use, the size of the partition, etc. As I said, I'm not familiar enough with the details to provide much advice, even if I knew the answers to these questions; but you might want to do a Web search to learn more about the performance characteristics of the two filesystems.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly have no idea what that guy is talking about in the last paragraph on the page you linked.

There is absolutely no problem at all with having different file systems on the same disk. If anything there needs to be an additional kernel module loaded for mounting the file system, but that doesn't affect performance nowadays at all.

I've personally been using ext4, ntfs and fat at the same time for years and have had no issues.

Comment: It's poorly phrased, but I think the last paragraph of the wiki is referring to the fact that NTFS makes a poor-to-unworkable choice for `/home` because it lacks support for key filesystem features needed in that directory tree. Also, in the past, the NTFS-3g drivers Ubuntu uses produced poor performance; but that's less true today than it was a few years ago. Mixing ext4fs and Btrfs should have little or no adverse affect, though, with the caveat that different filesystems have different performance features, so mixing the in a sub-optimal way may be a problem. (See my own answer.)

Answer (score 1):

No. There is a [command](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/slabtop1.html) called ...

> **slabtop**
>
> Displays  detailed  kernel  slab  cache information in real
>          time.  It displays a listing of the top caches sorted  by  one  of  the
>          listed  sort  criterias.   It  also displays a statistics header filled
>          with slab layer information.

I'll be you anything that each of the caches of each of the different filesystems is going to be close to 100%.

Yes, splitting the buffer cache is likely to take some performance away. But I doubt you can measure it.